# Retrieving token on Swagger

Tags: c#, http, post, xamarin.android, swagger

I need to retrieve token from [link](https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com/swagger/ui/index#!/User/User_Login).
But when I enter valid username and password I do not see any token. Also I tried to retrieve it in my C# Android program.

```
`var client = new RestClient("https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com/swagger/ui/index#!/User/User_LoginData");
request.AddParameter("username", login);
request.AddParameter("password", password);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;`
```

There are a lot of data in output but there is no token. How can I get deal with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The request URL is wrong.

```
https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com/swagger/ui/index#!/User/User_LoginData
```

is just a documentation page (aka Swagger UI), not the actual request URL.

To find out the actual URL, use Swagger UI's "Try it out" feature: fill out the operation parameters and click "Try it out". It looks like the correct URL is

```
https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com/UK/api/User/Login?username={login}&password={password}
```

where the login and password need to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

[image: Finding request URL in Swagger UI]

Also note the request HTTP method (`POST`), and that the parameters need to be passed in the query string. With all that in mind, your code should be:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com");
var request = new RestRequest("UK/api/User/Login", Method.POST);
request.AddQueryParameter("username", login);
request.AddQueryParameter("password", password);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I`ve replaced your code and have the same result.There is no token.

Comment: @S.Koshelnyk: What response are you getting (HTTP status and content)? Are you sure it's the right API call for getting the token?

Comment: look at the next method. It says that I should get the token in Login. [link](https://networkrail-uk-qa.traffilog.com/swagger/ui/index#!/User/User_LoginData)

Comment: Honestly, I've no idea what API this is and how it is supposed to work. If it's not working as expected, you should probably contact the API developers for support.

Comment: Besides `UK/api/User/Login` this API has `IL/api/User/Login`, `/DK/api/User/Login`, `/DEV/api/User/Login`, `/QA/api/User/Login` - maybe you need one of these instead? Just a thought.